# Open VPN Install Script error (CentOS 7)

Tags: centos, openvpn, centos-7, sh

this is the error I am getting when I attempt to create a new user

```
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/home/root/aaron.ovpn’: No such file or directory
./centos7-vpn.sh: line 984: /home/root/aaron.ovpn: No such file or directory
```

I am working on a VPS and I am pretty sure the root dir is `/root/`

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?